# How to use polars to get the rolling values for two dataframes col by col?

Tags: python, data-processing, python-polars

For example, I have two dataframes like:

```py
X = pd.DataFrame({f"id{i}": np.random.randn(200) for i in range(100)})
Y = pd.DataFrame({f"id{i}": np.random.randn(200) for i in range(100)})
```

In pandas, the rolling calculation of two DFs col by col (the columns with same id) can be writen easily by:

```py
# rolling corr:
X.rolling(5).corr(Y)

# rolling cov:
X.rolling(5).cov(Y)

# rolling slope:
X.rolling(5).cov(Y) / X.rolling(5).var()
```

How to use polars to implement such calculations?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to accomplish this, and still use `lazy`:

```py
dfX = pl.from_pandas(X).lazy()
dfY = pl.from_pandas(Y).lazy()

(
    dfX
    .with_row_count()
    .with_column(pl.col('row_nr').cast(pl.Int32))
    .with_context(
        dfY.select(
            pl.all().map_alias(lambda col_nm: col_nm + "Y")
        )
    )
    .groupby_rolling(
        index_column='row_nr',
        period='5i',
    )
    .agg([
        pl.cov(col_nm, col_nm + 'Y')
        for col_nm in dfX.columns
    ])
    .collect()
)
```

```
shape: (200, 101)
┌────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬─────┬───────────┬───────────┬──────────┬───────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ id0       ┆ id1       ┆ id2       ┆ ... ┆ id96      ┆ id97      ┆ id98     ┆ id99      │
│ ---    ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆     ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---      ┆ ---       │
│ i32    ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆     ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64      ┆ f64       │
╞════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 0      ┆ NaN       ┆ NaN       ┆ NaN       ┆ ... ┆ NaN       ┆ NaN       ┆ NaN      ┆ NaN       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ 0.198871  ┆ 0.021116  ┆ 0.140828  ┆ ... ┆ -0.023675 ┆ 1.240579  ┆ 0.457514 ┆ -0.486475 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 0.153685  ┆ -0.246208 ┆ 0.008931  ┆ ... ┆ -0.622545 ┆ -0.830773 ┆ 0.446357 ┆ -0.21538  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ 0.235759  ┆ -0.156201 ┆ -0.111072 ┆ ... ┆ -0.270532 ┆ -0.92131  ┆ 0.247192 ┆ -0.200723 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...    ┆ ...       ┆ ...       ┆ ...       ┆ ... ┆ ...       ┆ ...       ┆ ...      ┆ ...       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 196    ┆ -0.212265 ┆ 0.069828  ┆ -0.332518 ┆ ... ┆ 0.243745  ┆ 0.097037  ┆ 0.199009 ┆ 0.776244  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 197    ┆ 0.529492  ┆ 0.117366  ┆ -0.285602 ┆ ... ┆ 0.192653  ┆ 0.08174   ┆ 0.127401 ┆ 0.490955  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 198    ┆ 0.315249  ┆ -0.117771 ┆ 0.019203  ┆ ... ┆ 0.345703  ┆ -0.318349 ┆ 0.467904 ┆ 0.426183  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 199    ┆ 0.125482  ┆ 0.02746   ┆ 0.053431  ┆ ... ┆ 0.072234  ┆ -0.172202 ┆ 0.662359 ┆ -0.312281 │
└────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴─────┴───────────┴───────────┴──────────┴───────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `polars >= 0.17.12` there are specialized `rolling_cov` and `rolling_cor` expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with setting up the dataframe:

```py
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
X = pl.DataFrame({f"id{i}": np.random.randn(200) for i in range(100)})
```

There is currently no built-in `rolling_covarance`, in contrast to for instance [rolling_var](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rolling_var.html)

Thus we need two things:

1. set up the rolling bit. For this we use [groupby_rolling](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.groupby_rolling.html)
2. the actual covariance computation, using [polars.cov](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.cov.html)

My solution:

```py
# define a small helper function
def my_cov(c1: str, c2: str):
    return pl.cov(pl.col(c1),pl.col(c2)).alias(c1 + "_" + c2)

X.with_row_count()
.with_column(pl.col("row_nr").cast(pl.Int32))
.groupby_rolling(index_column="row_nr", period="5i")
.agg([my_cov(c1, c2) for c1 in X.columns for c2 in X.columns])
```

Lets break this down:

- `groupby_rolling` needs an index column. In contrast to Pandas, polars does not have indices. Usually that works out great, but this is one case where an index is handy. Polars solves this by allowing you to specify the column to use as index. `X` does not have an index column yet, so we create one using `with_row_count`, which emits it as `row_nr` and ensure it is `int32`, not the default `uint32` (for some reason `groupby_rolling` does not like unsigned integers as index column)
- the "5i" says we want a window of 5 observations
- the `agg` defines what we want to do for each row (including lookback). For each combination of columns in `X`, we want a covariance to be computed for that row. We use a list comprehension to set up the Polars expressions. `agg` will compute those in parallel. I factored out a bit of boilerplate into `my_cov` to keep the list comprehension readable.

Snapshot of the output:

```
shape: (200, 10001)
┌────────┬──────────┬──────────┬───────────┬─────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ id0_id0  ┆ id0_id1  ┆ id0_id2   ┆ ... ┆ id99_id96 ┆ id99_id97 ┆ id99_id98 ┆ id99_id99 │
│ ---    ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---       ┆     ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ i32    ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64       ┆     ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       │
╞════════╪══════════╪══════════╪═══════════╪═════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 0      ┆ NaN      ┆ NaN      ┆ NaN       ┆ ... ┆ NaN       ┆ NaN       ┆ NaN       ┆ NaN       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ 0.684141 ┆ 0.083535 ┆ -0.851174 ┆ ... ┆ -0.481743 ┆ -0.352858 ┆ -1.012102 ┆ 0.786184  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 0.343157 ┆ 0.017021 ┆ -0.427508 ┆ ... ┆ 0.356765  ┆ 0.322567  ┆ -0.267278 ┆ 1.029365  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
```

The nice thing is that you can easily create more complicated expressions:

```py
def my_beta(c1, c2):
   cov = pl.cov(pl.col(c1),pl.col(c2))
   return (cov / pl.col(c2).var()).alias(c1 + "_" + c2)
```

would give the beta of `c1` to `c2`.

Comment: I implemented it according to your answer, for example `X.rolling(5).cov(Y)`:
Firstly, rename columns with '_X' and '_Y' and then concat X and Y.
Then, change `my_cov` to `pl.cov(pl.col(c + "_X"),pl.col(c + "_Y")).alias(c)`.
The code can find [here](https://gist.github.com/Daic115/0efa60b62a6770038faaba8db42715e7). 
It looks a little complicated, after all, pandas only needs one line to implement this calculation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's my bad, "col by col" here only needs to calculate the columns with same id.

Comment: Ah, I missed you started out with two dataframes. Yes, you will have to join the two first.